Calendario Google
Pude bajar el archivo del calendario de mi cuenta en google a mi computadora, usando:
curl -O https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=ecferraro1974%40gmail.com&ctz=America%2FArgentina%2FBuenos_Aires
Devolvió el archivo: ecferraro197@gmail.com.ical
Modifiqué el archivo del calendario (.ical) actualizando algunos eventos. Intenté hacerlo con:
curl -T 'ecferraro1974@gmail.com.ical' https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=ecferraro1974%40gmail.com
El calendario no se modifica. Mis conocimientos de linux, Ubuntu y bash son muy pobres. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! no vas a poder hacer eso.. que te hace pensar que la info esta guardada en un archivo asi?? si queres hacer modificaciones al calendario, tenes una api para eso....

Muchas gracias, gbianchi. Muy atento... Evidentemente, hay mucho más por aprender. Pensé que la información podía estar guardada en un archivo ical porque:

así la baja a la laptop; y,

